# Many unwanted animation clips when import from Blender to Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, blender

I want to export my model from Blender (3.1) to Unity (2021.2).
I did some animations but i removed them because i want to create new ones. When exporting to Unity (after i deleted every animation) i still see all the old animations as clips (see screenshot).

[image]

How can i get rid of this in Blender?
I can't find anything else to delete. My timeline is empty and i selected all objects and clicked "Delete Keyframes..." and "Clear Keyframes..." under "Object" -> "Animation"

Answer (score 3):

Hi Zuyas maybe you can save it as .blend file and directly import it to Unity.

Or if you want to export it as FBX, then maybe you can follow the export options in this video
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=D-HDrhHgATo

***Transform***

- Forward: **Z Forward**
- Apply Transform: **Yes**

***Geometry***

- Apply Modifiers: **No**

***Armature***

- Only Deform Bone: **Yes**
- Add Left Bones: **No**

***Bake Animation***

- Key All Bones: **Yes**
- NLA Strips: **No**
- All Actions: **No**
- Force Start/End Keying: **No**

Comment: Amazing settings. Worked like a charm!

Answer (score 0):

In Blender "File" -> "Clean Up" -> "Recursive Unused Data-Blocks" fixed my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Clean up will resolve the Issue, Also if single animation clip needed, Then you need to uncheck NLA and ALL actions in the export tab